# How to use QueryDslJdbcTemplate with result transformation

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I'm using the `QueryDslJdbcTemplate` from spring-data-jdbc. Use case is, I'm joining 2 tables (qMainTable and qReferenceTable), and want the result grouped by the query condition. Main query looks like this:

`SQLQuery query = qdslTemplate.newSqlQuery().from(qMainTable).innerJoin(qReferenceTable)            .where(qMainTable.member.eq(qReferenceTable.member).and(qReferenceTable.userGuid.in(ImmutableList.of("a","b"))))`

I want the result look like this:

`"a" -> [qMainTable.row1, qMainTable.row2]
"b" -> [qMainTable.row3]`

I found QueryDsl support this type of transformation:

`query.transform(groupBy(qReferenceTable.userGuid).as(list(qMainTable))`

Question is, how to run this with Spring `QueryDslJdbcTemplate`? Thanks!